# How to group one more column and sum the amount of items? [SQL]

Tags: sql

orig : Como agrupar mais uma coluna e somar a quantidade dos itens

```
SELECT 
        u.nome,
        ef.nome AS nome_etapa,
        count(l.id) AS quantidade

        FROM usuario u
            LEFT join lead l ON l.id_usuario = u.id
            LEFT JOIN etapa_funil ef ON ef.id = l.id_etapa

                where
                    u.permissao = "2"
                        GROUP BY l.id, nome_etapa
                        ORDER BY u.nome, ef.posicao ASC;
```

Data

```
|nome     |nome_etapa|quantidade <br>
|Ana Paula| Entrada  |1| <br>
|Ana Paula| Perdidos |1| <br>
|Ana Paula| Perdidos |1| <br>
|Ana Paula| Perdidos |1| <br>
|Ana Paula| Perdidos |1| <br>
```

I need the last to group together and show the amount as 4

orig : Precisava que os perdidos agrupassem e mostrassem a quantidade como 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not group by ID.  Group by names instead

não agrupar por id.  agrupar por nome(s)

```
    SELECT 
    u.nome,
    ef.nome AS nome_etapa,
    count(l.id) AS quantidade
    FROM usuario u
        LEFT join lead l ON l.id_usuario = u.id
        LEFT JOIN etapa_funil ef ON ef.id = l.id_etapa
            where
                u.permissao = "2"
                    GROUP BY u.nome, ef.nome  <--GROUP BY nomes
                    ORDER BY u.nome, ef.nome ASC;
```